# What to look for when checking for linear (in)dependence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P \subset R^{4}$ be a set of vectors $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ where $x_{1} = (1,2,3,4)$, $x_{2} = (2,2,0,1)$ and $x_{3} = (1,2,a,2)$. Find for which $a$ is this set dependant.

This can easily be solved by Gaussian elimination. My teacher taught us to write each vector to one collum and do Gaussian elimination, then If one row is full of zeros, then this set is dependent.

So we get

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&1\\
   2 &2&2\\
   3&0&a \\
   4&1&2
 \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&1\\
   0&-2&0\\
   0&0&a-3 \\
   0&0&4
 \end{pmatrix}$

$rank(A) = 3$

From this I can see that for any value of $a$ we will get a row full of zeros (for $a = 3$ the third row, for any other value we can do one more step of Gaussian elimination and eliminate the last row). If I follow my teacher's steps, then since one row got eliminated, then the set $P$ is dependant. However the answer is supossed to be that for every value of $a$ this set is independent, which contradicts what my teacher said.

If I write the vectors in rows and do Gaussian elimination, I get this matrix:

$B =\begin{pmatrix}
   1&2&3&4\\
   0&-2&-6&-7\\
   0&0&a-3&-2
 \end{pmatrix}$

$rank(B) = 3$

It is obvious that for every value of $a$ the set is independent.

I did couple more exercises and found similiar errors so I came to this conclusion:

Set $S = (x_{1}, x_{2}, ...,x_{n})$ is independent if $rank(A) = n$; $A$ is matrix where collums are vectors from $S$.

Is my assumtion correct?

Comment: Yes. Same thing holds for an $A$ whose *rows* are the vectors from $S$, as your example shows (or, rather, as your example does not contradict)

Comment: The zero-row row only works for *square* matrices. Note that the rank of a $n \times m$ matric can always be at most $\min \{n,m\}$.